# Google Earth Pro install error

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-installation, google-earth

When I try to install Google Earth Pro software, it gives this error message.

> "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable."

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Save the installer file to a local drive and run it from there.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia i done it in your way. but it gives same error again

Comment: Where exactly have you saved it?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia In the C Partition

Comment: You shouldn't be saving thing in the root of C... You should save things in your user's area only. Saves the installer to your downloads folder, the typical location and run it from there. If it doesn't work download it again as it may have been corrupted. If it still doesn't work you have a serious problem.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Ok Thnx. I will try